# What are the required permissions to add SPN to Computer account

Tags: active-directory, rhel6

I am trying to add some RHEL6 boxes to an S2008R2 domain. Part of the [process](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/Configuring%20sssd%20to%20authenticate%20with%20a%20Windows%202008%20Domain%20Server#CreatingServiceKeytabonAD) is to create a computer account in AD, then add an SPN to it.

Pretty much all guides say that you need Admin privileges on AD, but that is not available to me. I want to give the Linux Admins the minimum rights possible on AD. Can any one tell me what rights they need on the target OU to do this?

Adding Computer objects is obvious, but then they cannot add the SPN.

If I take step back and try it from the Linux side (using *net ads join creatupn="host\jhgfjg"*) then it adds the object, but once again does not add the SPN

Answer (score 0):

I would start with Read ServicePrincipleName and Write ServicePrincipleName property permissions.

[image]